# How to Show Nodes under different flags in a view

Tags: flags

I have two flags, Flag A and Flag B. I need to have a view that lists the nodes that flagged under A and also the nodes that flagged under B.

Using Include only flagged content option in Relationship, I only get the nodes that are flagged by both the flags. But in my scenario I need nodes that are flagged either by flag A or flag B.

Comment: So you want A [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) B?

Comment: I need A OR B.By using filters in views I can get only A AND B

Comment: Got ya - in logic this is called XOR (exclusive or). What field type is your flag?

Comment: The flags are of node type

Comment: But your content can be either flagged A or B. So that is a field attached to your content type. What type is that field? "Node" is a type of entity, not a type of field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution for this question.

Refer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340423/or-operator-in-drupal-view-filters?rq=1

If you are using Views 3 / Drupal 7 and looking for the answer to this question, it is baked right into Views. Where it says "add" next to filters, click the dropdown, then click "and/or; rearrange". It should be obvious from there.